# HP P410 ADU (hpacucli) generates empty report

Tags: raid, monitoring, hp, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I'm trying to monitor hard drive's smart status. I've tried smartctl tools and HP's own hpacucli to generate ADU report. However, neither of them are useful. smartctl does not show values like Power On Hours or Hard drive temperature. ADU report shows them empty.

What's the right way to monitor hard drives with HP raid controller?

**Smartctl:** smartctl -a -d cciss,0 /dev/sg0

```
    smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-20-pve] (local build)
    Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

    User Capacity:        3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
    Logical block size:   512 bytes
    Logical Unit id:      0x5000c5003f11a168
    Serial number:        XXXXXXX
    Device type:          disk
    Local Time is:        Sun Jul 14 22:42:08 2013 HADT
    Device supports SMART and is Enabled
    Temperature Warning Disabled or Not Supported
    SMART Health Status: OK

    Current Drive Temperature:     <not available>
    Read defect list: asked for grown list but didn't get it

    Error Counter logging not supported
    Device does not support Self Test logging
```

**Hpacucli:** hpacucli ctrl all diag file=/usr/monitor/report.zip ris=on xml=on zip=on

```
    Smart Array P410 in slot 1 : Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I : Box 1 : Drive Cage on Port 1I : Physical Drive (3 TB SATA) 1I:1:12 : Monitor and Performance Statistics (Since Reset)

    Serial Number                        XXXXXXXX
    Firmware Revision                    0003    
    Product Revision                     ATA     ST33000650NS    
    Reference Time                       0x00001715
    Sectors Read                         0x00000000f868ca8b
    Read Errors Hard                     0x00000000
    Read Errors Retry Recovered          0x00000000
    Read Errors ECC Corrected            0x0000000000000000
    Sectors Written                      0x0000000016dd925d
    Write Errors Hard                    0x00000000
    Write Errors Retry Recovered         0x00000000
    Seek Count                           0x0000000000000000
    Seek Errors                          0x0000000000000000
    Spin Cycles                          0x00000000
    Spin Up Time                         0x0000
    Performance Test 1                   0x0000
    Performance Test 2                   0x0000
    Performance Test 3                   0x0000
    Performance Test 4                   0x0000
    Reallocation Sectors                 0xffffffff
    Reallocated Sectors                  0x00000000
    DRQ Time Outs                        0x0000
    Other Time Outs                      0x0000
    Drive Rebuild Count                  0 (0x0000)
    Spin Retries                         65535 (0xffff)
    Recovers Failed Read                 0x0000
    Recovers Failed Write                0x0000
    Format Errors                        0x0000
    Self Test Failures                   0x0000
    Not Ready Failures                   0x00000000
    Remap Abort Failures                 0x00000000
    IRQ Deglitch Count                   0 (0x00000000)
    Bus Faults                           0x00000003
    Hot Plug Count                       0 (0x00000000)
    Track Rewrite Errors                 0xffff
    Write Errors After Remap             0x0000
    Background Firmware Revision         0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Media Failures                       0x0000
    Hardware Errors                      0x0000
    Aborted Command Failures             0x0000
    Spin Up Failures                     0x0000
    Bad Target Count                     0 (0x0000)
    Predictive Failure Errors            0x00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to use `smartctl` and the like directly with these controllers. The HP Smart Array controllers use a variety of techniques to determine drive and system health. [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) is one of them, but not the ultimate determination. It makes to sense to take advantage of the purpose-built tools available.

So in your case, configure your hp-snmp-agents to send an email when there's an issue. On Linux, emails default to the root user and a message in the syslog, but configuring an alert destination can be handled in `/opt/hp/hp-snmp-agents/cma.conf`.

As for the `hpacucli` utility, running `hpacucli ctrl all show config detail` provides most of the relevant array health information.

Answer (score 0):

for me working like this

```
 smartctl -d cciss,0 -a /dev/cciss/c0d0


Device supports SMART and is Enabled
Temperature Warning Enabled
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     31 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        68 C
Elements in grown defect list: 0
Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 3203138637
  Blocks received from initiator = 3715997197
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 484569203
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 1111593814
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 0
Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 14706.28
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 33
```